# NSManageObject subclass can't initialized by alloc?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

> STEP:

First, i add an entity named **Employee** in the `.xcdatamodelId` and clicked -> product -> Created NSManageObject subclass.

After the first step I got `Employee.h/.m` which superClass is `NSManageObject` and `Employee+CoreDataProperties.h/.m`.

Then i want to save an employee 's info to Core Data as following in `Employee.m`:

```
+ (void)saveModelWithName:(NSString *)name startTime:(NSDate *)startTime birth:(NSDate *)birth {
Employee *employee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
if (name) {
    employee.name = name;
    employee.startDate = startTime;
    employee.birth = birth;
}
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context:%@\n%@",[error localizedDescription],[error userInfo]);
}
```

}
The data was inserted successfully. And i think the `Employee` was same as custom Class so
**i want to use this Class to save data in memory** and try to init `Employee` like

```
Employee *Sam = [[Employee alloc] init];

CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Employee'
```

I find the NSManageObject's Document says:

An NSEntityDescription object describes an entity in Core Data. Entities are to managed objects what Class is to id, or—to use a database analogy—what tables are to rows. An instance specifies an entity’s name, its properties (its attributes and relationships, expressed by instances of NSAttributeDescription and NSRelationshipDescription) and the class by which it is represented.

It seem that i can't save models in memory with the NSManageObject Class.
**Should i must custom a class with same property as `Employee` subclass NSObject?**
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but only for instances which are inserted into the context.

So:

1. You insert an object, you can then keep the reference to it to use later (`employee` in your code)
2. You use an `NSFetchRequest` to get an instance from the context and keep it for later

You 'can not' create an instance which isn't inserted into the context - this is the cause of the error you get. You can use an init method, but it must be `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` (or another init method that uses that method internally).

The above is 'can not' because technically you can pass `nil` for the context when calling that init method, but there are very few reasons you ever should...

Comment: Thx for your answer.It help me understand more